# Unknown column 'v_plateno' in 'where clause' in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update, prepared-statement

this is my Table vehicletlb  !

`Field      Type
v_branch    varchar(255) NULL
v_segment   varchar(255) NULL
v_company   varchar(255) NULL
v_name      varchar(255) NULL
v_plateno   varchar(255) NULL
v_seats     int(11) NULL
v_fuel      varchar(255) NULL
v_priceperkm   int(11) NULL
v_driver    varchar(255) NULL`

Now I am trying to Update the table using Prepared Statement in Servlet. But unfortunately it is giving error for unknown column:v_plateno

Also the update query is working fine for other Tables in the database

```
public void updateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle)  {

    String updateQuery = "UPDATE vehicletlb SET v_branch=?, v_segment=?, v_company=?, v_name=?, v_seats=?, v_fuel=?, v_priceperkm=?, v_driver=? WHERE v_plateno = ? ";


    try {
        pStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);     

        pStmt.setString(1, vehicle.getVbranch());
        pStmt.setString(2, vehicle.getVsegment());
        pStmt.setString(3, vehicle.getVcomp());
        pStmt.setString(4, vehicle.getVname());
        pStmt.setInt(5, vehicle.getVseats());
        pStmt.setString(6, vehicle.getVfuel());
        pStmt.setInt(7, vehicle.getVprice());
        pStmt.setString(8, vehicle.getVdriver());
        pStmt.setString(9, vehicle.getVplateno());


        pStmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0 
But it gives error

```
Unknown column 'v_plateno' in 'where clause'
```

How can I solve it !!!!

Comment: Did you make sure that you are connecting to the correct database? Perhaps it's the production/development/staging database and that table doesn't have the column there?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your Java.  But the table that you're trying to update doesn't have a v_plateno column.  So you've either made a mistake creating the table, or you've got the table name wrong, or you're connecting to the wrong schema within the database, or to the wrong database.  So check all of those things.

Comment: I am using MySQL.  Yes, I am using Correct Database and Correct Table

Comment: The [info for the sql-server tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) states "[Microsoft's SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver) is a suite of ***relational database management system*** (RDBMS) products providing multi-user database access functionality...Do not use this tag for other types of DBMS ([tag:mysql], [tag:postgresql], etc.)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were no errors in the program and now
I tried **Refreshing the Browser**, and it started working

Thanks for support !